# Cannot access portable disk from (s)chroot jail

Tags: permissions, chroot

I want to access the files in my portable hard disk, so I bind-mount the `/media` directory to the schroot jail by adding a line

```
/media          /media          none    rw,bind         0       0
```

to its corresponding config file `/etc/schroot/.../fstab`.

In the jail, I could see the mounted directory by run `ls -l /media/[my.username]`

```
total 4
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 Dec  9 01:32 Seagate Expansion Drive
```

But the problem is that I could not read or write the directory.

While if I run the same command `ls -l /media/[my.username]` outside the jail, the directory permission is set correctly.

```
total 4
drwx------ 1 [my.username] [my.username] 4096 Nov 15 15:50 Seagate Expansion Drive
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.  I should have rbind-mount the directory,

```
/media          /media          none    rw,rbind         0       0
```